# Why do Express apps use server.js and app.js

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to express. In most examples I've seen, including the official [express sample](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) app and the official [typescript sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter/tree/master/src) app, there are two main files: `server.js` and `app.js`. The server imports the app.

Why this separation? There must be a good reason for this to be the norm, but it's never explained.

---

UPDATE: see the accepted answer, as well as my lengthy comment under it. There was a reason for this pattern, it was just never explained properly by the express team and so people just copy-pasta without thinking.

Comment: That's just how someone decided to organize it, then other people followed suit.

Comment: @KevinB No it's a strange split, and I'm sure there is a reason to it. I suspect it has something to do with isolation for testing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: There isn't. You can split it up however you feel is best. Some even skip both and just start with index.js

Comment: To whoever downvoted me - if this is the norm across the entire node/express industry, and it's never explained EVER, just stated as fact, then surely this is a good question for newcomers to the platform? Even if the answer is that it was an arbitrary split, then that still is relevant.

Comment: *You* were not downvoted.

Comment: @KevinB I was but someone reversed it! :)

Comment: your post was downvoted, you were never downvoted (people can't be downvoted here)

Comment: @KevinB Wow you're splitting hairs. You know exactly what I meant. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no answer to this question that isn't just a single person's opinion. anyone can speculate on why this may have occurred, but to know why it actually occurred, you'd need someone with knowledge of what the person who originally made the separation intended by doing so. There's several advantages to doing so, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: Most apps use it simply because thats what the app they copied code from used.

Comment: @KevinB there is always more than one way of doing things, the difference is in looking for the best one to be able to do a good job. In this case, the question is well because it is important to know why things do not just make them meaningless.

Comment: Best one for what? readability? performance? testability? least amount of code? least amount of dependencies? some combination of all of the above? Each person/teams needs are different. there is no single best way to separate code/logic.

Comment: @KevinB It's exactly what I said "look for the best", when you plan the idea is to solve a need so you are free to choose what most suits your development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a good practice to have everything in an organized way and not in a single file.

In this case `server.js` is used to start the web server where we can stipulate the port and other configurations, and in the `app.js` file is where the routes and middleware are added to the express application.

So we can continue having everything in different layers where for example we can have the detail of our routes with their respective controllers, another layer where the data repository is stipulated, etc, etc.

In short the idea of having this is order and organization of the code, when making changes or maintenance a clean code makes things easier.

Comment: There is sense to that yes. We can isolate everything in server that has to do with http. Everything in app is specifically for the app. And that isolation is good for testing. This is what I suspected. The problem is that you can start listening in app.js as well, so it gets messy like you said :)

Comment: Right! The main idea is to keep your code organized by dividing the configuration and routing logic in different places so that it is easy to keep track of everything.

Comment: I mean, generally routing logic doesn't go in app.js

Comment: @KevinB Calm down my friend, your opinion is fine and is accepted, anyway I don't say that goes in `app.js` just mention the idea of having everything separated.

Comment: @ccordon I agree with your analysis, lots of experience tells me this must have been the reason for this pattern, but was never explained. In other frameworks, ASP.NET Core for example, the same pattern is used - there is a bootstrapping / server class, and then your app class. The bootstrapper spins up the server and loads config and does "critical" stuff like logging init and server-level errors, whereas the app is the actual app and in theory doesn't care how it is run, or care about server-related errors, only app-related errors. And of course all that makes testing much easier.